# Why does Clojure hang after having performed my calculations?

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

I'm experimenting with filtering through elements in parallel. For each element, I need to perform a distance calculation to see if it is close enough to a target point. Never mind that data structures already exist for doing this, I'm just doing initial experiments for now.

Anyway, I wanted to run some very basic experiments where I generate random vectors and filter them. Here's my implementation that does all of this

```
(defn pfilter [pred coll]
  (map second
    (filter first
      (pmap (fn [item] [(pred item) item]) coll))))

(defn random-n-vector [n]
  (take n (repeatedly rand)))

(defn distance [u v]
  (Math/sqrt (reduce + (map #(Math/pow (- %1 %2) 2) u v))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [[n-str vectors-str threshold-str] args
        n (Integer/parseInt n-str)
        vectors (Integer/parseInt vectors-str)
        threshold (Double/parseDouble threshold-str)
        random-vector (partial random-n-vector n)
        u (random-vector)]
    (time (println n vectors 
      (count 
        (pfilter 
          (fn [v] (< (distance u v) threshold))
          (take vectors (repeatedly random-vector))))))))
```

The code executes and returns what I expect, that is the parameter n (length of vectors), vectors (the number of vectors) and the number of vectors that are closer than a threshold to the target vector. What I don't understand is why the programs hangs for an additional minute before terminating.

Here is the output of a run which demonstrates the error

```
$ time lein run 10 100000 1.0
     [null] 10 100000 12283
     [null] "Elapsed time: 3300.856 msecs"

real    1m6.336s
user    0m7.204s
sys 0m1.495s
```

Any comments on how to filter in parallel in general are also more than welcome, as I haven't yet confirmed that `pfilter` actually works.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to call `shutdown-agents` to kill the threads backing the threadpool used by pmap.

About `pfilter`, it should work but run slower than `filter`, since your predicate is simple. Parallelization isn't free so you have to give each thread moderately intensive tasks to offset the multithreading overhead. Batch your items before filtering them.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks. I'm not really going to use it for simple distance queries, but it was an easier example. Thanks.